# math Oparator for disjoint sets

Tags: amsmath

I want to denote disjoint sets with the following oparator.

[image: Opa]

and I want to be able to set bounds for it, as for the mathematical sum oparator.
I have not found a solution that allows me to continue using the amsmath package.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=dotted+union